# how can I insert frame at particular index in video using ffmpeg or opencv

Tags: java, ffmpeg, video-processing

We are doing a project of data hiding in Video. We want to hide data in one of the frame of video file and the frame number will be stored in the audio file. Hiding of information in frame is working in our case.

I have 2 questions here 
1. I am able to extract a frame from position N in video but I don't know on how to insert the modified frame back to video. 
I tried following command but it results in video loss

`[ ffmpeg -i Wildlife.wmv -f image2 -i "D:/testing/2.png" -f image2 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=enable='between(n,450,451)'[out]" -map "[out]"  -r 25 -c:v png "D:/testing/output.wmv" -y ]`

2. Extracting the output video is changing the quality and size of the video.

Please help me with ffmpeg or any other framework that provides this functionality